# Android how to measure time (few days) in app

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-timepicker

Sorry if the title is confusing, I'll explain:
I am making an app which registers an action of the user, writes it in the database as a string (like this, 17JUL2014 17:45), and then, from when the first entry is created I have to measure 3 days, so when those 3 days pass, I will prompt the user to do something. How will I be able to do that?

Comment: sorry I was pretty sleepy yesterday, see my updated answer. Of course you don't have to multiply by 60, 1000ms*3600 seconds == 1 hour * 24 *3 == 3 days

Comment: I just calculated the exact time in milliseconds and wrote it in a String, but the other part was more important, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use Unix time and save it as `long`.

```
 long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

3 days difference:

```
 boolean isThreeDaysDifference(long savedTime){
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - savedTime > 1000*3600*24*3)
          return true;
      return false;
 }
```

**EDIT** corrected the value